# Moves for regular homotopies of immersions of $S^1$ in the plane

Tags: differential-topology, knot-theory

What is a set of moves to combinatorially describe regular homotopies of (smooth) immersions $S^1\to \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: AFAIR two such immersions are equivalent iff they have the same winding number (H. Whitney. On regular closed curves in the plane), no?

Comment: Yes, that is what I remember (thanks for the reference!)

Comment: I think, you mean regular homotopy, not isotopy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC (I can't find a good reference at the moment), one needs just two «Whitney moves»:

[image: pictures of two moves]